# How to get the ant build xml file's own name?

Tags: ant, filenames

let's say I have a file named `build_dev_linux.xml`.

My question is

How can I find the ant script XML file's own name, `build_dev_linux.xml`
so I can put it on variable or property in that XML file.?

Comment: Why cant you directly set a property containing the name

Comment: To reduce handling points

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ant defines a useful list of built-in properties:

```
basedir             the absolute path of the project's basedir (as set
                    with the basedir attribute of <project>).
ant.file            the absolute path of the buildfile.
ant.version         the version of Ant
ant.project.name    the name of the project that is currently executing;
                    it is set in the name attribute of <project>.
ant.project.default-target
                    the name of the currently executing project's
                    default target;  it is set via the default
                    attribute of <project>.
ant.project.invoked-targets
                    a comma separated list of the targets that have
                    been specified on the command line (the IDE,
                    an <ant> task ...) when invoking the current
                    project.
ant.java.version    the JVM version Ant detected; currently it can hold
                    the values "1.2", "1.3",
                    "1.4",  "1.5" and "1.6".
ant.core.lib        the absolute path of the ant.jar file.
```

The `ant.file` property is what you need. If you want just the file name without the path then you can use the `basename` task like

```
<basename file="${ant.file}" property="buildfile"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know where to start, and now I think I have one.:)

Comment: `<dirname property="antfile.dir" file="${ant.file}"/>` could be useful as well, see https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html